# Grafana Mimir - SNMP data source

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, snmp, grafana-mimir

I've installed on a Ubuntu VM the basic MIMIR+GRAFANA tutorial configuration.
In my environment, i've actually some elements that have a pre-installed prometheus and can be actually be monitored by grafana + mimir, but the major part of my elements use a basic SNMP protocol to send data. i didn't find out anything about this protocol to ingest data into MIMIR, so i have a few question:

- it's possibile to send or retrieve data using snmp and store them into mimir?
- if it's possible, i need to install a Grafana agent on each NE that i need to monitor? Or in this configuration the Grafana Agent is pre-installed and i need just to configure it in some way? (i have more than 100 element to monitor).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a [Prometheus SNMP exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/snmp_exporter)?